# React multiple forms with single submit handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have a common event handler for form submit

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const errors = this.validate();
    this.setState({ errors: errors || {} });
    if (errors) return;
    this.doSubmit();
  };
```

It will handle validation and call another function doSubmit(); If I have 3 different forms, all forms calls doSumbit();

How to make different submission call based on the related form... also how to handle related form field validation...

Comment: could you maybe add some examples of your forms and what you've tried?

Comment: You know you have 3 different forms, and all forms you want to use the same 'doSubmit' but yet you want to have different 'submission calls'. Based on these, I think , I'm getting the impression that you want to save some lines of code, what you could do is maybe use 3 different 'doSubmit', extract the part that you reuse like validation part. coz with your current code I think you got it reversed, that is if I'm correct with my assumption

Answer (score 0):

As I understood. You have to give each form an id.
And then you can use this.

```
if(e.target.id==='formid1'){
      console.log('formid1');
}
else if(....
```

Answer (score 0):

**      you can use for="id of your form" in your button **

```
 <form id="myForm" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
        <center><button for="myForm" type="submit">Continue</button> </center>
        </form>
```